# Numpy compute dot product of arrays of N-d vectors

Tags: numpy, math

I want to compute a dot product of an array of vectors stored as rows using Numpy. Given a and b each array of M vectors of 2 components with both of shapes as (M, 2). I want to compute `ab^T` along axis 0.

I did tried the following which seems to work by writing the product as matrix product on paper but I feel there must exists a better way without the need of allocating a matrix.

My current version:

`np.diag( ( a @ b[:, :, None]).reshape(a.shape[0], a.shape[0]) )`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I encountered the einsum function which with the bellow indexes produces the same result as my first try:

`np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, b)`

Comment: The  matmul equivalent will use a (m,1,2) with a (m,2,1) to produce a (m,1,1) and then squeeze out the 1's.  The 'batch' dimension has to be the first of 3.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What is the batch dimension? i?

Comment: In your `einsum`, `i` carries through; the "dot", or sum-of-products is the `j` dimension.  `np.matmul` describes what it does with dimensions N>2, `it is treated as a stack of
  matrices`.  In your first code the shapes evolve as: `(m,2) with (m,2,1) =>(m,m,,1) => (m,m) => (m)`.  I'm saying, make both `a` and `b` to be m-stacks, so the result is also a m-stack.